# $http GET refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, get

I'm working on a project and i'm beginner at html,css,javascript and angular. Im using API from a site with movies and their data is in json and sorted by pages

```
    {
"page": 1,
"results": [
{
"poster_path": "/1yeVJox3rjo2jBKrrihIMj7uoS9.jpg",
"popularity": 14.31312,
"id": 1396,
"backdrop_path": "/eSzpy96DwBujGFj0xMbXBcGcfxX.jpg",
"vote_average": 8,
"overview": "Breaking Bad is an American crime drama television series created and produced by Vince Gilligan. Set and produced in Albuquerque, New Mexico, Breaking Bad is the story of Walter White, a struggling high school chemistry teacher who is diagnosed with inoperable lung cancer at the beginning of the series. He turns to a life of crime, producing and selling methamphetamine, in order to secure his family's financial future before he dies, teaming with his former student, Jesse Pinkman. Heavily serialized, the series is known for positioning its characters in seemingly inextricable corners and has been labeled a contemporary western by its creator.",
"first_air_date": "2008-01-19",
"origin_country": [
"US"
],
"genre_ids": [
18
],
"original_language": "en",
"vote_count": 858,
"name": "Breaking Bad",
"original_name": "Breaking Bad"
},
```

I have managed to list the TV shows on screen but i have a problem because of pages variable. when i use $http.get i use this url https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/top_rated?api_key=ap_key&language=en-US&page=1, how do i change page and autorefresh page so it shows the page two on button click.

```
        Mpage=1;
        TVpage=1;

        nextM = function(){Mpage++;}

         $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=040eb2b1bb7d1697319a08872e2578cb&page='+Mpage)
         .success(function(data) {
         $scope.Mresults = data.results;
         })


         $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=040eb2b1bb7d1697319a08872e2578cb&page='+TVpage)
         .success(function(data) {
         $scope.TVresults = data.results;
         })
```

Comment: First off don't mix jquery and angular unless you really know what you are doing and must use jquery plugins for features not available in angular modules. There are numerous pagination modules available for angular already that you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the attached snippet. It should give you an idea on how you can achieve this.

PS: The snippet will not run as I haven't executed angular directives. But a simple jquery snippet to give you an idea how you can make it work.

```js
$(function(){
  _pagination.initialize();
});

var _pagination = {
  initialize: function(){
    $('.pagination').on('click', function(){
      var page = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[2];
      _pagination.getPageData(page);
    });
  },
  getPageData: function(page){
     $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=040eb2b1bb7d1697319a08872e2578cb&page='+page)
         .success(function(data) {
         $scope.Mresults = data.results;
         })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="pagination_btn_1" class="pagination">1</button>
<button type="button" id="pagination_btn_2" class="pagination">2</button>
<button type="button" id="pagination_btn_3" class="pagination">3</button>
<button type="button" id="pagination_btn_4" class="pagination">4</button>
<button type="button" id="pagination_btn_5" class="pagination">5</button>
```